# SQL group by month and add 15mins

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with data every 15mins.

I have this query :

```
Select Sum(Value) From MyTable Group By month(myDate), year(myDate)
```

However the result is not what i want because I have values from

'2013-01-01 00:00:00.000' to '2013-01-31 23:45:00.000' and I need to have values from

'2013-01-01 00:15:00.000' and '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000'

How can I change the request to have the correct date range ?

Thanks

Comment: You can create this table in your query using a recursive CTE and join it to your table.

Comment: Adding 15 minutes to 23:45 would give you some values in February which would otherwise  have been in January. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) method:

```
SELECT Sum(Value)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MONTH(DATEADD(minute,15,myDate)), YEAR(DATEADD(minute,15,myDate))
```

Comment: Thanks ! Actually, I had to remove 15 mins to have the result I expected. No idea why :p